# Laravel 5 Publishing Assets

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5 and I want to publish twitter bootstrap CSS and JS to public directory.
I did used Composer to get twitter/bootstrap package and that part went OK, so files I want are now in **vendor/twitter/bootstrap/dist**

But I can't get it to work. I get 'Nothing to publish.' message every time I try.
Here are the steps I took:

- use artisan to generate class: `php artisan make:provider BootstrapServiceProvider`
- edit the `boot()` method in that class
- register service provider in config/app.php
  `providers => [ 
  ...

  'App\Providers\BootstrapServiceProvider',

  ],`

Bellow is my generated file with the class and it's edited `boot()` method.

**BootstrapServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class BootstrapServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     * Move twitter bootstrap CSS and JS into public directory
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->publishes([
                     __DIR__ . 'vendor/twitter/bootstrap/dist' => public_path('vendor/bootstrap'),
        ], 'public');
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

}
```

I have tried:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=public
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=public --force
php artisan vendor:publish
php artisan vendor:publish --force
```

And also tried with removed second `'public'` parameter from boot() method.

Every time I get **Nothing to publish.**.

boot() method doesn't even get called.
What do I have to do to get it to working?
Maybe put something in the `register()` method? Right now is just empty.
Or some other step?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To answer my own question.

After reinstalling Laravel from 5.0.26 to 5.0.25 everything worked.
Even after updating it again to 5.0.26 and higher it still works.

I don't know why it didn't work before composer update.

Everything else is the same as above except `boot()` method has to be fixed to point to the right vendor path when calling `publishes()`.

Fixed version of `boot()`:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->publishes([
        __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/dist' => public_path('vendor/bootstrap'),
    ], 'public');
}
```

To automate it all add this entries in composer.json in `scripts:` section under *"post-install-cmd"* and *"post-update-cmd"*:

```
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
          "...",
          "php artisan vendor:publish --tag=public --force"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
          "...",
          "php artisan vendor:publish --tag=public --force"
    ],
},
```

Comment: Thanks, please note that post-update-cmd is only available for root package, Adding this code in child-packages won't work.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#scripts indicates that scripts is only available on the root package.

Answer (score 6):

**How to install Bootstrap in Laravel using composer**

Although it has been a year since this question was posted, I believe my response is going to help someone out there. This works perfectly for me.

I am using Laravel Framework version 5.2.31 (do `php artisan --version` to check your Laravel version). Follow the steps below:

1. Open the terminal and run `composer require twbs/bootstrap 3.3.6`. If you want a different version from 3.3.6, check the latest distribution version on https://packagist.org/packages/twbs/bootstrap.
2. Create a Bootstrap service provider class using artisan command: `php artisan make:provider BootstrapServiceProvider`
3. Open your Bootstrap service provider class in `app/Providers/BootstrapServiceProvider.php`. Edit the `boot()` method as follows:

   `public function boot()
   {
      $this->publishes([base_path('vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist') => public_path('vendor/bootstrap')],'public');
   }`

   The code above will instruct `artisan` to copy directory `vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist` to `public/vendor/bootstrap`.
4. register service provider in config/app.php by adding `DealerPortal\Providers\BootstrapServiceProvider::class,` below the list of *Application Service Providers*
5. Run `vendor:publish --tag=public --force` to complete this task.

**Bonus step:**

If you want to automate the process of publishing Bootstrap all add `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=public --force` to `post-install-cmd` and `post-update-cmd` section of your `composer.json` file.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the path below worked for me:  (thanks for the rest of the answer)

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->publishes([
    vendor/twitter/bootstrap/dist' => public_path('vendor/bootstrap'),
    ], 'public');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This also may be caused by config cache. if you get this kinda error , use php artisan config:clear

and retry php artisan vendor:publish